# Should dependency schema be compiled too?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

In mongoose I have the following Schemas in a single file:

```
var CoinSchema = new Schema({
  ...
});
var WalletSchema = new Schema({
  coins: {
    type: [CoinSchema]
  }
});
```

I don't know how should I export this Schema.
Do I need to export the model of both of these ?
Or is exporting the dependent schema the way below, enough?

```
module.exports = mongoose.model('Tasks', TaskSchema);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should declare and export both models.
Also, you should change your `coins` property to be of type `ObjectID`, referencing the `Coin` model:

```
var CoinSchema = new Schema({
  ...
});

const coinModel = mongoose.model('Coin', CoinSchema);

var WalletSchema = new Schema({
  coins: {
      [
          type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
          ref: 'Coin'
      ],
  }
});

const walletModel = mongoose.model('Wallet', WalletSchema);

module.exports = {
    coinModel,
    walletModel
}
```